# jQuery scan table th's for * and give parent a color

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a rather (for me) complicated task with jQuery.

I want to scan an entire table for its th elements. If a th element has a ASTERISK (*) in it, I want to highlight the the parent, which is the tr element.

I know it sounds complicated when I explain it :)

So imagine I have a dynamic html table where I want to enable a feature to higlight certain rows. Therefore I just want to put some symbol (in my case an Asterisk *) to some text inside of a table cell. if jQuery detects a asterisk inside of th it should automatically give its parent() a classname!

A start would be probably an each function:

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr th").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass("special");            
    });
});
```

but I have no idea how to scan for the asterisk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could help:

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr th").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('*') > -1)            
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("special");            
    });
});
```

EDIT: You'd probably want the `th` itself to have a `special` class as in the demo [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/d945N/)

Comment: do have also an idea how i could remove the aterisk afterwards? so it's just there to know which th/tr should be special, but i don't want to actually show it in the table. is there a string-remove method in jquery?

Comment: Again, you would only need the native JavaScript `.replace()` for this - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
`$(this).addClass("special").text($(this).text().replace('*',''));`

Comment: awesome. i tried with replace but couldn't quite figure it out. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way:

```
$("table tr th:contains('*')").parent().addClass("special");
```

[Example at jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fPAYp/)

**Edit from reading OP's comment:**

In order to remove the asterisk, you'll need to iterate over the found elements:

```
$("table tr th:contains('*')").each(function(){
  var $This=$(this);

  $This.parent().addClass("special"); /* Add the "special" class */
  $This.text($This.text().replace("*","")); /* Remove the asterisk */
});
```

[Example with asterisk removal.](http://jsfiddle.net/v6R7W/)